# How do I approach this triple integration problem? In regards, to picking the right confined domain.

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: image of problem]

I want to know how to integrate with respects to $dx\ dz\ dy$. So far I  know the domain of $y$ is $0 \le y \le 1$ . However, I'm completely lost when I try to get the correct values for the other domains ( $x$ and $z$), since there is some weird business going on with the $x$ and $y$ relationship. What's the best way to approach these problems? Thank you!

Comment: Since you are given $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x$ it might be better to sum in the $x$ direction last.

Comment: Hmm, I know I could do 0 <= z <= 1 - sqrt(1-z) and 0 <= x <= sqrt(1-z). But, for some reason that does not bode well with me. It seems like I'm just manipulating things rather than seeing the big picture, per say.

Comment: $z$ goes from $0$ to $1-x^2$, $y$ goes from $0$ to $1-x$ and $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$

Comment: Ah, The question is asking to find five other orders, and the most troubling order I have concocting is the dxdzdy order.